# to_excel error: ValueError: <Worksheet ""> is not in list

Tags: export-to-excel, valueerror

I'm quite stumped here. I'm using pandas version 1.3.5 and am trying to replace an excel tab with new data from a dataframe. Seems extremely simple using the below:

```
Workbook = load_workbook(file_path + '\\' + file_nm + '.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path + '\\' + file_nm + '.xlsx', mode="a", engine='openpyxl',if_sheet_exists='replace')

writer.book = Workbook

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Positions_auto', index=False)*
```

However, when trying to replace I'm getting the below error:

ValueError: <Worksheet "Positions_auto"> is not in list

I'm googled far and wide and haven't seen similar issues with to_excel.

Any thoughts? I have no clue why it's not working as the documents say.

I feel like i've tried everything

Comment: did you ever found the answer? encountering the same problem